# Describe the image of the set $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Im(z) >0 \}$ on the Riemann sphere.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Describe the image of set $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Im(z) >0 \}$ under stereographic projection onto the Riemann sphere.

I know that if I have a complex number $z$, then the stereographic projection $f: \mathbb{C} \to S^2$ is given by
$$
f(z) = \left(\frac{z + \overline{z}}{1 + |z|^2},\frac{z - \overline{z}}{i\left(1 + |z|^2\right)},\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1}\right)
$$
and similarly, given a point $(a,b,c) \in S^2$ I know that the inverse stereographic projection $f^{-1}:S^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ is given by
$$
 f^{-1}(a,b,c) = \frac{a+ib}{1-c}
$$

---

### My solution

Since I didn't really have a good idea of where to start with this, I decided to make a [GeoGebra plot](https://www.geogebra.org/m/kybrrxmw) to get a feel for where the numbers with positive imaginary part landed on the sphere.  After playing around with it for a while, It seemed to me that all the points landed on the set
$$
B=\{(a,b,c) \in S^2: \ |a|\le 1, \ \color{blue}{0< b< 1} \} \subset S^2
$$
So from here, I tried to prove that $f(A) = B$. To accomplish this, I attempted to use double inclusion.

- To show that $f(A) \subseteq B$ I noticed the following. Since $\Im(z) = \frac{z -\overline{z}}{2i}$, this means that the second entry of $f(z)$ can be seen as $b=\frac{2 \Im(z)}{1 + |z|^2}$, and if $\Im(z) >0$ then clearly under the projection I would have $b >0$, which I think is enough to justify that $f(A) \subseteq B$ since $f(z) \in S^2 \ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.
- For the second inclusion, I needed to show that given $(a,b,c) \in S^2$ with $b>0$ then $\frac{b}{1-c} >0$. This basically reduces to show that $1-c>0$, since the numerator is already positive by hypothesis. To do this I argue by contradiction, so I assume $1-c \le 0$ which implies
  $$
  1\le c \implies 1^2 \le 1-a^2 -b^2 \implies a^2 + b^2 \le 0
  $$
  but since $a^2 + b^2 >0$ this creates a contradiction, and hence our assumption was wrong. This then shows that $\Im\left(f^{-1}(a,b,c)\right)>0$ if $b >0$.

#### Notes:

1. I use $\color{blue}{b<1}$ instead of $b \le 1$ since the equiality in the latter case only happens if for $z = x + iy$ we would have $2y = x^2 + y^2 +1$, which (I believe) has no solutions for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. I say that $a^2 + b^2 >0$ since I think the equality only happens for $(0,0,1)\in S^2$, which corresponds to the point at infinity, which is not on the complex plane.

---

I found this problem to be a bit tricky and with a lot of "special cases" in need of consideration, so I'm not sure if my solution might have missed some of these cases or if I argued correctly in the parts I did write.

Could anyone tell me if my attempt is correct? Thank you!

Comment: I recommend not using the formula for this, but instead to imagine geometrically what the stereographic projection is supposed to be. It will be pretty obvious with the correct geometric image in your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I say $S_2$, I'll be excluding the point at infinity for simplicity.

I think that $f(A) = \{(a,b,c) \in S_2, y > 0\} = B$. For any complex number $z$, we have that $z - \overline{z} = 2i\Im(z)$ as you noted so the $b$ value of $f(z)$ would be $$b = \frac{2\Im(z)}{1 + |z^2|}.$$ This shows that $f(A) \subseteq B$.

For the reverse inclusion, suppose we had some $(a,b,c) \in S_2$ so that $y > 0$ (and by assumption, $c \neq 1$). By the surjectivity of stereographic projection, there is some complex number $\zeta$ so that $f(\zeta) = (a,b,c)$. Given the formula for $b$ above, we can then conclude that $\zeta \in A$. Thus, $B \subseteq f(A)$.

In conclusion, your reasoning was right but your definition of $B$ is a little redundant. Since stereographic projection is onto the unit sphere, $|a| \leq 1$ for all $(a,b,c) \in S_2$. Also, $b = 1$ is in the image of $A$. Consider $f(i)$ for example.